# Recursively serialise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, recursion

I am consuming a data structure from Contentful, which looks like this:

```
{
  sys: {}
  fields: {
    type: 'page',
    children: [
      {
        sys: {}
        fields: {
          type: 'section',
          children: [
            ...andSoOn
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to recursively serialise the data with the following pattern:

```
const serialise = entry => entry.fields
```

Basically, I want to flatten out the `fields` nested object, and remove the `sys` object.

How can I do this recursively, for any number of nested `children`?

Comment: Can you provide your expected result to make the question a little clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify the exact desired output, but I guess this is what you're looking for:

```js
const data = {
  sys: {},
  fields: {
    type: 'page',
    children: [
      {
        sys: {},
        fields: {
          type: 'section',
          children: [
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const flatten = ({ fields }) => ({ ...fields, children: fields.children.map(flatten) });

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allInOne = []
function seeker (item) {
  const { fields: { type, children } } = item
  const obj = { fields: { type } }
  allInOne.push(obj)
  children.forEach(seeker)
}

seeker(nestedObj)
```

like this?